# Rename all stored procedures in SQL in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have more than 200 stored procedures in a SQL Server database.

Our stored procedure name start with `SP_{CAPITAL_LETTER}`.

Now we want to change all the stored procedure's names to `proc_{{small_letter}}`.

For example: currently we have a stored procedure called `SP_EMPLOYEE_LIST` and we want to rename it to `proc_employee_list`.

Do we have any common way to rename all stored procedures using some T-SQL query instead of renaming them one by one?

Thanks,
Hitesh

Comment: and what about callers of these procedures ? Are they notified ?

Comment: You could dump them all the SQL, rename them, and then reload the SQL file.

Comment: Do any of the stored procedures call other stored procedures? Renaming the objects isn't going to fix any of the stored procedure references in code, you'll have to find and fix those as well.

Comment: @Sergey yes they are notified.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning we will take care all those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dump a script to do all of this and then just run the script

```sql
select STRING_AGG(CAST(
    'exec sp_rename @objname = N' + QUOTENAME(s.name + '.' + p.name, '''') + ', @newname = N' + QUOTENAME(LOWER(STUFF(p.name, 1, 3, 'proc_')), '''') + ', @objtype = ''OBJECT'';'
    AS nvarchar(max)), '
')
from sys.procedures p
join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = p.schema_id
where p.name like 'sp[_]%';
```

You can even put that into a variable and run it through `sp_executesql` if you are that (fool-)hardy.

Comment: Don't forget the `LOWER`, as the OP wants lowercase names now.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks. it is working now